# How to redirect to a particular pipeline instance in a delivery pipeline view in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, delivery-pipeline, build-pipeline-plugin

I am using the **Delivery pipeline** plugin for grouping my jobs into stages.
Currently, there seems no mechanism to directly go to a particular older pipeline instance in the view.
I wanted to provide a provide a mechanism(posssibly a link) in the Initial job(**JobI**) of the pipeline so that whenever I click on a particular build of the **JobI**, it should redirect me to that **particular pipeline instance of the pipeline** view directly.
I also tried to achieve the above behavior via some other pipeline plugins i.e **Build pipeline** etc. but no solution.
The idea is to make the view easy to use for a user,so that he does not have to take the pain of scrolling through all the instances to get to a particular instance.

I want to replicate the behavior of the "builds in the jobs"  for the "versions of the view" or similar to that.

[image]

Any help/suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Build Graph View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Graph+View+Plugin) to view the executions of downstream builds.

But this plugin doesn't have a grouping of jobs as stages, it is plain flow graph.